# Query a time series, update each row with start date of a shift that overlaps to a new day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains some shift information for an employee(s)

```
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
| empid | StartDate  |    StartTime     |  EndDate   |     EndTime      | ShiftDate  |
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 | 22:00:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 | 22:15:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 22:15:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 00:00:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 00:45:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 02:30:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 02:45:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 04:30:00.0000000 | ?          |
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 21:45:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 21:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 22:00:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 00:00:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 00:45:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 02:30:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 02:45:00.0000000 | ?          |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 04:30:00.0000000 | ?          |
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
```

I need to update the ShiftDate Column with the StartDate for this shift.  So below are 2 different shifts that EACH span over 2 days.  The first shift the ShiftDate for each row should be 2014-12-16 and the second shift, each row's ShiftDate should be 2014-12-17.

Expected Result:

```
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
| empid | StartDate  |    StartTime     |  EndDate   |     EndTime      | ShiftDate  |
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 | 22:15:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-16 | 22:15:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 04:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-16 |
+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 21:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 21:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-17 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 00:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 02:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
|   391 | 2014-12-18 | 02:45:00.0000000 | 2014-12-18 | 04:30:00.0000000 | 2014-12-17 |
```

+-------+------------+------------------+------------+------------------+------------+

I cannot work up a way to determine the shift date from the given rows.  When it's a new shift, the Shift StartTime would never be the same as the Shift's previous EndTime.

I'm working with SQL 2008 R2

Any suggestions to get me going in the right direction would be great!

Comment: can you update the question with expected output

Comment: Added the expected result, perhaps a better column name should of been ShiftStartDate

Comment: I can't see how you can do this - how do you know that those two blocks are a different shift other than by inspection?

Comment: Will shift of 15th starting at 20:00:00 end by 17th 19:59:59? Is it for 2 days? @kdunlapmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT  empid, StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY StartDate, StartTime) AS RowNumber
        FROM    EmployeeShift
    ),
    CTE2 AS (
        SELECT  empid, StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime, 
                StartDate AS ShiftDate,
                RowNumber
        FROM    CTE1
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  c1.empid, c1.StartDate, c1.StartTime, c1.EndDate, c1.EndTime,
                CASE
                    WHEN c1.StartDate = c2.EndDate AND c1.StartTime = c2.EndTime THEN c2.ShiftDate
                    ELSE c1.StartDate
                END AS ShiftDate,
                c1.RowNumber
        FROM    CTE1    c1
        INNER JOIN CTE2 c2 ON c1.empid = c2.empid AND c1.RowNumber = c2.RowNumber + 1
    )

SELECT * FROM CTE2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

A commentor asked for its internals so here it goes:

1. Each shift entry is numbered 1,2,3,...,n by each employee, and sorted according to its start and end date. This is `CTE1`
2. For the first shift entry, the `ShiftDate` is the same as its `StartDate`. This is the first half of `CTE2`.
3. From the first shift entry, it recursively goes through the next entry for the employee. If the next entry's Start Time is the same as previous entry's End Time, it carries on the previous `ShiftDate`. Otherwise it sets the `ShiftDate` to the current shift's `StartDate`.

Comment: This is correct solution and if @ZoffDino describe its internals in more details it becomes undestandable in less time.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!